# Consolidate scene components state in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, scene

i'm trying to consolidate scene components state in a classic dashboard application.
My need is to restore all the components values/states in a specific scene when the user navigates through the dashboard menu (which allows to load various scene in a given content pane).
Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Any example on how doing this?

Comment: Your question is, I believe, too broad ([help/on-topic]) and an example would take too much explanation. In essence, you're asking how best to design an entire application. Try reading up on some design patterns for GUI apps such as MVC (Model-View-Controller) or MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel). JavaFX with FXML seems to favor MVC. If you run into _specific_ issues while implementing this please feel free to come back and ask a new, specific question ([ask]). This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx

Comment: In the end i solved the problem binding each component state to the relative model property